# How this error occure in ionic installation?

Tags: ionic-framework

I can't install ionic in windows 10 please help me to install and configure the ionic s/w

I already changed my node version and `node-gyp` command. but nothing changed

An error occurred while running `node install (exit code 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Run this

first uninstall ionic completly

```
 npm uninstall -g cordova
 npm uninstall -g ionic
```

install again

```
npm install -g ionic
```